# How to test linux NAPI feature?

Tags: linux, networking, embedded, ethernet, interrupt

I am trying to test the **NAPI** functionalities on embedded linux environment. I used '**pktgen**' to generate the large number of packets and tried to verify the interrupt count of my network interface at */proc/interrupts*.

I found out that interrupt count is comparatively less than the packets generated. Also I am trying to tune the '**netdev_budget**' value from **1** to **1000(default is 300)** so that I can observe the reduction in interrupt count when netdev_budget is increased.

However increasing the netdev_budget doesn't seems to help. The interrupt is similar to that of interrupt count observed with netdev_budget set to 300.

So here are my queries:

1. What is the effect of 'netdev_budget' on NAPI?
2. What other parameters I can/should tune to observe the changes in interrupt count?
3. Is there any other way I can use to test the NAPI functionality on Linux?(Apart from directly looking at the network driver code)

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a [comprehensive blog post about Linux network tuning](https://blog.packagecloud.io/monitoring-tuning-linux-networking-stack-receiving-data/) which explains everything about monitoring, tuning, and optimizing the Linux network stack (including the NAPI weight). Take a look.

Keep in mind: some drivers **do not** disable IRQs from the NIC when NAPI starts. They are supposed to, but some simply do not. You can verify this by examining the hard IRQ handler in the driver to see if hard IRQs are being disabled.

Note that hard IRQs are re-enabled in some cases as mentioned in the blog post and below.

As far as your questions:

1. Increasing `netdev_budget` increases the number of packets that the NET_RX softirq can process. The number of packaets that can be processed is also limited by a time limit, which is not tunable. This is to prevent the NET_RX softirq from eating 100% of CPU usage. If the device does not receive enough packets to process during its time allocation, hardirqs are **reneabled** and NAPI is disabled.
2. You can also try modifying your IRQ coalescing settings for the NIC, if it is supported. See the blog post above for more information on how to do this and what this means, exactly.
3. You should add monitoring to your `/proc/net/softnet_stat` file. The fields in this file can help you figure out how many packets are being processed, whether you are running out of time, etc.

A question for you to consider, if I may:

Why does your hardirq rate matter? It probably doesn't matter, directly. The hardirq handler in your NIC driver should do as little work as possible, so it executing a lot is probably not a problem for your system. If it is, you should carefully measure that as it seems very unlikely. Nevertheless, you can adjust IRQ coalescing settings and IRQ CPU affinity to distribute processing to alter the number of hardirqs generated by the NIC and processed by a particular CPU, respectively.

You should consider whether you probably are more interested in packet processing throughput or packet processing latency. Depending on which is the concern, you can tune your network stack appropriately.

Remember: to completely tune and optimize your Linux networking stack, you have to monitor and tune each component. They are all intertwined and it is difficult (and often incorrect) to monitor and tune just a single aspect of the stack.

Comment: How do enable napi on the driver? I see I've napi supported driver but how interrupts matches the packet rate

Comment: Looks like even if you change netdev_budget and weight using "sysctl -w", there may not be any change in the overall performance. I think these kernel parameters are not used as it is, instead it is hardcoded in the driver and NAPI(dev.c). Can anybody confirm on this?